# Enabling springs and structs in latest xcode

Tags: ios, view, storyboard, size

Learning iOS for first time, but the demo I'm fulling has size and structs enabled, by I'm running the latest iOS and Xcode and don't see that. I have a custom view in my storyboad that takes up the whole view. How do I see/enable size and struts?

Comment: Do you mean springs and struts?

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html and  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about "springs and struts", as rdelmar said, just keep AutoLayout set to ***OFF*** in your storyboard or XIB files.

like this:

[image: Turn off AutoLayout]